Highcharts Stock using the Chart.from_pandas method
can someone please share a simple example on how to use Chart.from_pandas method to draw a candlestick chart within Jupyter. My Dataframe contains the tandard Datetime, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume + some others. An example on the site would have been nice. I have been going around in circles and have not found the documentation. I am sure it will be me (casual programmer at best) but I am fairly lost with the many options. TY in advance.
I am needing to create this result:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/candlestick-and-volume

from highcharts_stock.chart import Chart
from highcharts_stock.global_options.shared_options import SharedStockOptions
from highcharts_stock.options import HighchartsStockOptions
#from highcharts_stock.options.plot_options.bar import BarOptions
from highcharts_stock.options.series.bar import BarSeries

import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

tsla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
df = tsla.history(period="1y")
df.tail(3)

my_chart = Chart.from_pandas(
    df,
    property_map={
        'date': 'Date',       # Prob wrong but cannot find info
        'open': 'Open',       # Assumed from dict examples.
        'high': 'High',
        'low': 'Low',
        'close': 'Close',
        'volume': 'Volume'
    },
    series_type= Candlestick,
    series_kwargs = {
        'point_padding': 0.5
    },
    options_kwargs = {
        'title': {
            'text': 'This Is My Chart Title'
        }
    },
    chart_kwargs = {
        'container': 'my_target_div'
    })

my_chart.display()


Please share your jupyter-notebook with us so we could see your code and all the errors. You can use online editor for that. Waiting for your answer!

Hi Dominik, thanks for responding. If I had anything worth sharing I would be happy to but the fact is I am lost with the documentation and have not found a reference that clarifies how to map a dataframe with OHLC to highcharts using the .from_pandas method. Keep in mind that many people wanting to do this (including myself) are traders and not developers).  The examples I found only cover lines and bars. How about an example that uses a data from and displays the hollow candlesticks chart? Examples work!
I have added a basic skeleton if that helps.

Hi Dominik, just adding a little - the details of the series_type argument seems to be my primary issue. In the documentation there is a section that mentions that this is detailed in "Supported Visualizations" in the documentation. I am unable to find this.

The series_type Argument.
Using the series_type argument, you determine which series type will be used to visualize your data. You can find a complete list of supported series types in the Supported Visualizations section of our documentation.
In the example above, we use all of the default settings for the CandlestickSeries that gets created, but you can further configure your series by passing its configuration options in a series_kwargs argument. That argument expects a dict whose keys map to the series properties you wish to configure, and whose values are the values that you can apply.

This approach suggested by Chris did not work for me.
I got:
HighchartsValueError: series_type expects a valid Highcharts series type. Received: <class 'highcharts_stock.options.series.candlestick.candlestickseries'
So I did some reverse engineering of the code in the official git depository:
https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-for-python-demos/blob/master/highcharts-stock/hlc-and-ohlc-charts/hlc-chart.ipynb
And converted my padas.DataFrame into JSON string representation. (I did not find any case in official documentaion where DataFame was used, if you know any please post it)
What I did:
droped unnecesary columns
df = df[['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]

drop NAs
df = df.dropna(subset=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])

converted my DataFrame from descending to ascending (don't have to do it if it is already correct)
df = df[::-1]

Convert the date to UNIX time stamp
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda date: int(dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").timestamp() * 1000))

converted to list with format of ints and float
data_list = df.apply(lambda row: [int(row['date']), float(row['open']), float(row['high']), float(row['low']), float(row['close'])], axis=1).tolist()

dump it to JSON
json_string = json.dumps(data_list) 

created Chart using json_string as data using Chart.from_options(
as_dicts = {
    'range_selector': {
        'selected': 2
    },
    'title': {
        'text': 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },
    'navigator': {
        'enabled': True
    },
    'series': [
        {
            'type': 'candlestick',
            'name': 'AAPL Stock Price',
            'data': json_string
        }
    
    ]
}
chart = Chart.from_options(as_dicts)
chart.display()

Hope this helps at least some LLM model.

Quick Update: Wrote to Highcharts and it seems like there is a bug in Chart.from_pandas. They promised to fix it.

I'm Chris, the primary author of Highcharts for Python. Your code is almost correct, but there's one slight tweak. When you supply series_type as an argument, you need to either supply the class for the series (CandlestickSeries) or the name of the series type (candlestick).
So you could use the following code:
from highcharts_stock.chart import Chart
from highcharts_stock.global_options.shared_options import SharedStockOptions
from highcharts_stock.options import HighchartsStockOptions
from highcharts_stock.options.series.candlestick import CandlestickSeries

import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

tsla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
df = tsla.history(period="1y")
df.tail(3)

my_chart = Chart.from_pandas(
    df,
    property_map = {
        'x': 'Date',
        'open': 'Open',
        'high': 'High',
        'low': 'Low',
        'close': 'Close',
    },
    series_type = CandlestickSeries,
    series_kwargs = {
        'point_padding': 0.5
    },
    options_kwargs = {
        'title': {
            'text': 'This Is My Chart Title'
        }
    },
    chart_kwargs = {
        'container': 'my_target_div'
    })

my_chart.display()

And since it may be helpful, here's a link to the documentation for the:

CandlestickSeries: https://stock-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/api/options/series/candlestick.html#highcharts_stock.options.series.candlestick
CandlestickData: https://stock-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/api/options/series/data/candlestick.html#highcharts_stock.options.series.data.candlestick.CandlestickData

In addition, the candlestick series does not support "volume" directly within it, though it does support x, high, low, open, and close properties. If you are looking to recreate a volume tracker below your candlestick series you'd need to use the Navigator functionality described here: https://stock-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/using.html#working-with-highcharts-stock-features (basically you need to add the Navigator class to your chart, and supply a volume-specific series to the Navigator class).
You can find more documentation on configuring the Navigator functionality here: https://stock-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/api/options/navigator.html#highcharts_stock.options.navigator.Navigator and in particular I recommend looking at the Navigator.series property here: https://stock-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/api/options/navigator.html#highcharts_stock.options.navigator.Navigator.series
Hope this helps!

Thanks Chris, I really appreciate you taking the time to response and thank you for all your work. I am very keen to put it to work! The updated example does not work? Using a cut & paste, I still get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\luthor\PycharmProjects\Hurst\StackOverflow.py", line 14, in 
my_chart = Chart.from_pandas(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\luthor\PycharmProjects\Hurst.venv\Lib\site-packages\highcharts_stock\chart.py", line 988, in from_pandas
raise errors.HighchartsValueError(f'series_type expects a valid Highcharts '
highcharts_core.errors.HighchartsValueError: series_type expects a valid Highcharts series type. Received: <class 'highcharts_stock.options.series.candlestick.candlestickseries'>
